# INSERT statement not working using Insight.Database with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, insight.database

I am using Insight.Database for Oracle. I am trying to get an insert statement to work but keeps failing with an "ORA-00936: missing expression" exception. Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
var myQuery =
    @"insert into MySchema.MyTable (Field1, Field2, Field3)" +
    " values (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)";
var myParameters = new { Value1 = 12345, Value2 = 67890, Value3 = "MyFileName" };
var myResult = db.ExecuteSql(myQuery, myParameters);
```

Please can someone help me in this regard?
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `:` for bind variables

```
var myQuery =
    @"insert into MySchema.MyTable (Field1, Field2, Field3)" +
    " values (:Value1, :Value2, :Value3)";
var myParameters = new { Value1 = 12345, Value2 = 67890, Value3 = "MyFileName" };
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The examples were very confusing.